# Can I set a default "About Me" photo?

Tags: login-screen, default, icons, user-profile

Is there a way to set a default "About Me" photo so that all users created in the future start off with the same user image on the login screen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, simply place an image file named `.face` in `/etc/skel`.

```
sudo cp new_photo.jpg /etc/skel/.face
```

**NOTE:** Not all image formats will work, so stick to PNG and JPEG.

The `/etc/skel` directory contains files and directories that are automatically copied over to a new user's home directory when the user is created.

> The name of the directory skel is derived from the word skeleton, because the files it contains form the basic structure for users' home directories.

<sup>Source: http://www.linfo.org/etc_skel.html</sup>